# 301 permanent redirect not working in htaccess

Tags: .htaccess, redirect

we are facing urls like "http://domain.com/p/post-content/%3Ca%20href=", these urls generate 404 errors, when we have tried to redirect something like that

```
Redirect 301 /p/post-title/<a href= /p/post-title/
```

But its not working, please anybody let me know, how to redirect url like this

Comment: What this `<a href=` ???

Comment: These html tags included in urls, its some kind of bugs in urls

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The extra space is messing up the statement, apache will think there are too many arguments. Try:

```
Redirect 301 "/p/post-title/<a href=" /p/post-title/
```